# Youtube API beginner, searching for a list of different terms automatically

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have no idea if I'm allowed to ask questions here, because I'm a complete beginner and I need help for a university paper I want to write. I need to search for quite a big list of terms in the YouTube API with a specific regioncode, location, locationradius, publishedafter and publishedbefore term.

So basically I need to do queries like [these](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=de#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&location=54.470037612805754%252C-4.0869140625&locationRadius=531km&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2014-10-01T00%253A00%253A00Z&publishedBefore=2015-10-01T00%253A00%253A00Z&q=music+parody&regionCode=GB&type=video&_h=16&), but for the same search term I have to change these parameters a few times and I have to do that for a lot of search terms.

Does anyone have a good guide that shows how to do this? Or would someone be willing to help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find YouTube API search examples in every major language in [this Github repository](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples).  The reference for this API endpoint as well as the list of parameters available for the search.list call is available [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#request-body).

You'll need an API key to use the API which you can get by:

1. Going to the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential) (create an developer account and API project if you haven't already).
2. Enabling the YouTube API on your API project [on this page](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/library).
3. Clicking Add credentials > API key and selecting "sever key"